# Why is this web page loading so slow?

Tags: html, iframe

Can anyone please help with the iframe in the following page:

http://searchbankproperties.com/bank-owned-properties-orlando/

2 questions:

1. I don't understand why the page is loading slow..
2. Is it possible to only display the main content of the page I'm trying to iframe without the header and navigation?  See the link below.

> http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4123/4941392626_3886396314_b.jpg

The websites is http://searchbankproperties.com

The page I'm trying to iframe is located in http://searchorlandoproperties.com

Answer (score 1):

In order to pintpoint a problem like that I'd recommend that you use a tool like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and look at what resource takes the most time to load. Then try to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to load the page on Chrome, not blazingly fast but acceptable (less than 1 second), then tried on Firefox, takes more time (between 2 and 3 seconds). Finally tried on IE... you can go and take a coffee in the meanwhile ;)

That time basically depends on two factors: iframe rendering (that's a browser business, you can't do much about it) and page downloading speed, which depends on how much data has to be downloaded. Try to work on that second factor if you can...

About the second question: it's "theoretically possible" via javascript but before doing this try to see if you can produce a lightweight version of the iframed page on searchorlandoproperties.com.

Comment: hahaa,, definitely grap a cup of coffee while waiting for internet explorer to load.  I'm not very familiar with coding.  Any ressources out there where I can just plug the code?

Comment: I found nothing out-of-the-box, but here you can find a tutorial on how to access iFramed content with JQuery: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/09/access-iframe-content-using-jquery.html

JQuery has a useful function called hide(), by which you can hide elements from the iFramed page. This, anyway, doesn't remove any content which is still fully downloaded (so no performance benefits).

Comment: Thank you for the message..:)  Unfortunately, the solution does not work if its not in the same domain...